# PHP MySQLi : String being converted to int?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a php function that is saving a 32 character token to a mysql database using a mysqli prepared statement.  The issue I am having is that when this 32 character alpha-numeric token is inserted into the database only the first set of contiguous numbers are stored if the token begins with a number, otherwise 0.  For example:

- 47f1f737fe813b9f19ecadc524eddcc1 is stored as 47
- cba73ec72629938c92b5bb81207c8b0b is stored as 0
- 1c1348bb3f85f006151b0111b5ae26f7 is stored as 1

Table setup is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_password_tokens` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `token` (`token`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_password_tokens_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The relevant php code is:

```
$log->add("ID: " . $parameters['data']['id'] . " | Token: " . $parameters['token']['value'], 1);
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO user_password_tokens
    VALUES (?, ?, NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id, token=VALUES(token), expiration=VALUES(expiration)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $parameters['data']['id'], $parameters['token']['value']);
$stmt->execute()
```

The logging statement at the beginning of the PHP code produces the expected value for the token. Also the token is being passed via API call to another service which is receiving it correctly. Has anyone ever seen something like this or have a clue what is going on?

EDIT: I will add that interacting directly with the database using my database client will allow me to store the whole value, so it does not appear to be a problem with MySQL or the table definition itself, but rather somehow the value is being altered by the prepared statement.  My best guess anyway.

PHP version 5.5.26, MySQL version 5.0.96

A secondary question is why do I have to pass the int 'id' as a string for the prepared statement to succeed?  Cannot get it to work as an int in bind_param.

Comment: So my findings after messing with this for another day are that using a standard query works fine, but the prepared statement seems to require that I bind all params as strings, otherwise the query fails.  I have tried using a variety of PHP functions to typecast the INT values and then use them with no success.  At this point, my best guess is that the MySQL version is outdated enough that it is having trouble with the prepared statement.  This is causing the trouble binding params correctly and the wacky data input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After updating the mysql and php version on both the client and server machines the problem has disappeared.  It appears that even though MySQLi was said to be supported on the versions I was running it was not without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of answer.

> somehow the value is being altered by the prepared statement

Prepared statements do not alter your data. All the alterations can be done by means of the user code only. Check your code.

> why do I have to pass the int 'id' as a string

You don't have to. If you cannot get it to work, then you are doing something wrong. Double-check your code.

Comment: The question wouldn't have been posted if I hadn't already gone over it 30-40 times.  "Look at it again" does not add value.